# Page object model in selenium

Tags: selenium, nullpointerexception, pom.xml

Can anyone please resolve the issue in the below post.

[Selenium Framework Page Object Model and Page Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34145422/selenium-framework-page-object-model-and-page-navigation/34147044#34147044)

I am not able to resolve the null pointer exception issue when a page returns an object of other page. Can anyone please tell what is the exact way of doing it. As explained in the above link, it's not clear how the error is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In the below example, We have created a  **Login class** , **Home class**, and a **Test class** ...

It is not necessary to create one class for one page may be you can group the functionality or modules based on your convenience...

**Summary:-**

- Created Login Class with all the required objects...and the **loginas** method should return the **homepage** class.....

  ```
    public class LoginPage {
        private final WebDriver driver;

        public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
            this.driver = driver;

            // Check that we're on the right page.
            if (!"Login".equals(driver.getTitle())) {
                // Alternatively, we could navigate to the login page, perhaps logging out first
                throw new IllegalStateException("This is not the login page");
            }
        }

        // The login page contains several HTML elements that will be represented as WebElements.
        // The locators for these elements should only be defined once.
            By usernameLocator = By.id("username");
            By passwordLocator = By.id("passwd");
            By loginButtonLocator = By.id("login");

        public LoginPage typeUsername(String username) {
            driver.findElement(usernameLocator).sendKeys(username);

            // Return the current page object as this action doesn't navigate to a page represented by another PageObject
            return this;    
        }

        public LoginPage typePassword(String password) {
            driver.findElement(passwordLocator).sendKeys(password);

            // Return the current page object as this action doesn't navigate to a page represented by another PageObject
            return this;    
        }

        public HomePage submitLogin() {
            // This is the only place that submits the login form and expects the destination to be the home page.
            // A seperate method should be created for the instance of clicking login whilst expecting a login failure. 
            driver.findElement(loginButtonLocator).submit();

            // Return a new page object representing the destination. Should the login page ever
            // go somewhere else (for example, a legal disclaimer) then changing the method signature
            // for this method will mean that all tests that rely on this behaviour won't compile.
            return new HomePage(driver);    
        }



        // Conceptually, the login page offers the user the service of being able to "log into"
        // the application using a user name and password. 
        public HomePage loginAs(String username, String password) {
            // The PageObject methods that enter username, password & submit login have already defined and should not be repeated here.
            typeUsername(username);
            typePassword(password);
            return submitLogin();
        }
    }
  ```

**2. Created Homepage class** , I have added only a sample verification  method here , may be you can add methods as per your application needs...

```
class HomePage {
    private final WebDriver driver;

    public HomePage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;

        // Check that we're on the right page.
        if (!"HOME".equals(driver.getTitle())) {
            // Alternatively, we could navigate to the login page, perhaps
            // logging out first
            throw new IllegalStateException("This is not the home page");
        }
    }

    // below method is just a sample method
    public HomePage verifyRecords() {

        /// your homepage validation
        return null;
    }
}
```

3. Now we are going to see how to put the above class together and make it work as per your requirement...

   class Test {

   ```
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            LoginPage login = new LoginPage(new FirefoxDriver());

            // login and verify records in home page
            login.loginAs("myname", "pass@@").verifyRecords();

        }
    }
   ```

In this line `login.loginAs("", "").verifyRecords();`   we are calling a method from login class and the method that is being called would return HomePage class....

You can create any no of pom classes and return it like the above......Like create some thing like dashboard and return it from homepage class

**How returning page works :-**
login.loginAs("myname", "pass@@").verifyRecords();

In the above code once this `login.loginAs("myname", "pass@@")` snippet executes , it will complete the login action and returns this method  `submitLogin();` which in turns returns new HomePage......
Here once execution of `login.loginAs("myname", "pass@@")` is done it will become new Homepageobject..... Javacompiler is smart enough to manipulate that and provides the Homepageobject's methods once you put a dot after `login.loginAs("myname", "pass@@").`

Comment: I want to know how a page will return an object which points to another page in page object model.Suppose we have 2-3 web pages and as per POM,we will have separate classes for all these pages.Now if a click on 1st page takes us to 2nd page,then the method in 1st page should return the object of the 2nd page as per POM.I want to how that is done i.e establishing relationship between different pages as per POM.

Comment: try to replicate the above said example in your system...Here we have Login.java for Login webpage and HomePage.java for Homepage webpage.....Java method return type feature allows to return new object...return new HomePage(driver); <-this line creates new object of home page..... By returning submitLogin() from loginAs method we should be able to return Login page.....

Comment: I tried using the same thing,but i am getting the issue when i am using page factory method.

Comment: I am not able to enter my code here.It says too long.Could you please let me know how can i enter my code here?

Answer (score 0):

I will try illustrating PageFactory example using 3 different classes types.

Base Class- Has configuration setting like driver declaration

POM Class- Contains the POM objects for a single page

Test Class-Class containing test steps

**BaseClass Example**

```
public class BaseClass {
 public WebDriver driver=null;
 public BaseClass() throws MalformedURLException {
        driver=new firefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(baseURL);
 }
```

**POM Class example**

```
  //Class1
public class WebshopHomePage {
WebDriver driver;
public WebshopHomePage(WebDriver driver){
    this.driver=driver;
}

@FindBy(how=How.LINK_TEXT,using="Log in")//Identifying page elements
WebElement loginLink;

public void clickLoginLink(){
    loginLink.click();
}
}

//Class2
public class SignInSignUpPage { 
WebDriver driver;

public SignInSignUpPage(WebDriver driver){
    this.driver=driver;     
}

@FindBy(how=How.ID,using="Email")
WebElement emailID;
}
```

**TestClass Example**

```
public class WebShopSignInTest extends BaseClass {
@Test
 public void testSteps() {

System.out.println("I'm in teststeps!!");
WebshopHomePage wshpObj=PageFactory.initElements(driver,WebshopHomePage.class);//Assigning POM class1 objects to driver
wshpObj.clickLoginLink();


SignInSignUpPage signInSignUpPageObj=PageFactory.initElements(driver, SignInSignUpPage.class);//Assigning POM class2 objects to driver
signInSignUpPageObj.enterCredsSubmit(userID, passw0rd);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Prithvi for the above example.However,this is the basic example it involves only 1 page if you see,as we are just doing a login to the application..I was asking about what if there are 2-3 POM classes for 2-3 pages like homepage,downloads and so on.In that case,how will we establish relationship between different pages.If you see the link which i shared http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34145422/selenium-framework-page-object-model-and-page-navigation/34147044#34147044 ,in this the same thing is mentioned.I want to resolve null pointer exception in that case.

Comment: @dheerajkateja: I just made some edits to the example .Notice 2 POM classes, there is no need to establish relationship as long as you are using the same instance of driver throughout the test i.e. there is no need to return objects from POM class.Hope this answers your question

Comment: The same principle extends to multiple POM classes

Comment: Thanks Mate.I will make note of the same and will try to apply the same logic.So the methods wont return any values and there wont be any relationship between them or pages.

Comment: @dheerajkateja Exactly,not needed unless you need to assert some values in your test class.Just ensure to maintain single instance of driver throughout the test!Please accept the answer if i was able to solve your query!

Comment: I will try it and will accept if my code runs.If you have similar example for scenario where the methods will return some values or like to establish relation between pages,that would be nice.Anyways i will accept this once my code runs without any issues.Thank you for your time over this

Comment: Cool.As stated before, there is no need to create relationship between pages since it is handled internally by single instance of driver

Comment: Yes got it .Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

package org.pom;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class GoogleHomePageObjects 
{

```
 public GoogleHomePageObjects(WebDriver driver) 

 {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
 }

@FindBy(name="q")
public WebElement txtSearch;

@FindBy(name="btnG")
public WebElement btnSearch;

@FindBy(linkText="Selenium - Web Browser Automation")
public WebElement lnkSelenium;


public  void searchGoogle(String SearchText)

{

    txtSearch.sendKeys(SearchText);
    btnSearch.click();
}
public SeleniumPageObjects clickSelenium()
{
    lnkSelenium.click();
     return new SeleniumPageObjects(driver);    //Here is the issue and i am      getting error
}
```

}

//test class 2

package org.pom;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class SeleniumPageObjects{

```
public SeleniumPageObjects(WebDriver driver) 

{

PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

}




@FindBy(linkText="Download")
public WebElement lnkDownload;  

@FindBy(xpath=".//*[@id='header']/h1/a")
public WebElement lnkHome;

public void clickDownloads()
{

    lnkDownload.click();//Here it throws null pointer excception
}

public void clickHome()
{

    lnkHome.click();
}
}
```

Below is my main class:

package org.pom;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class GoogleSearchTest
 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
```

{

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\Desktop\\Selenium\\Jars\\geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");

 WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    GoogleHomePageObjects page=new GoogleHomePageObjects(driver);


    page.searchGoogle("Selenium");

    Thread.sleep(4000);

    SeleniumPageObjects selPage=page.clickSelenium(); 

    Thread.sleep(4000);


    selPage.clickDownloads();

    Thread.sleep(4000);

    selPage.clickHome();
    }
```

}

Comment: I have 2 test classes and one main class,I am trying to enter search selenium in google and then click on the first link(Selenium website).Once it clicks on the first link,the page changes                                               public SeleniumPageObjects clickSelenium()
{
    lnkSelenium.click();
    return new SeleniumPageObjects(driver);   
}                                                                                                                Its showing error at this point.Could you please explain how to achieve the same.

Comment: My issue is resolved.Thank you for your help and time over this.